# How to change the location of Firestore without losing the ID of my project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a problem. A long time ago, I created a project with the name "Milano-Models" (milano-models.firebaseapp.com) I'm in South America and at that time it was still not possible to select the location of Cloud Firestore.

I discovered that it is NOT possible to change the location of a project.
The solution is to create a new project with the locations that bring me closer.

This is where I have my little problem. By doing this, I lose full control of the name "milano-models.firebaseapp.com". If I delete it and try to recreate it, it will show me that the name (or project ID) already exists and I will not be able to use it again.
I think it must be because the project is not completely eliminated in 30 days.

I care about the name, especially now that the subdomain "web.app" will soon be enabled and I'll be able to use "milano-models.web.app"

I do not like the solution "milano-modelos-2354", for example.

I hope it was understood. Is there a way to solve this without waiting for maybe 30 days?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the given hostname, but if the URL of your hosted site in a Firebase project matters to you, you should register your own domain and [connect it to your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).  With this, you can move your custom domain to any project you want, at any time.